# Are there any conditional compilation constants I can use?

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-construction

Are there any built in conditional compilation constants that I can use to check if I'm running in debug or release build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not by default, no.  But it is easy to add to your build configuration to do this. Here is an explanation of compiler flags and conditional compilation.

[AS3: Conditional Compilation Demystified](http://www.boostworthy.com/blog/?p=227)

Some IDEs (such as FlashDevelop) will add `CONFIG::Debug` and `CONFIG::Release` to the build configuration for you

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried to edit the post to change Degub to Debug which is what I think you meant and then ran into all sorts of validation errors with stack overflow minimum character limit which can't be less than 6 characters. So I had to add more content which messed up your answer so then I tried to change it back to what it was and that said I had to add more content. In the end I added a bunch of periods. Whatever the case someone should be able to cancel the edit. But I agree with Stack Overflow. No edits could possibly be valid if they are less than 6 characters. :P